# MongoImport upsert creating new document

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to update 12,000 records with specific values.  The values a different per document in mongo so i figured mongoimport could be used.  I have a csv file that contains all correct values to be updated in the system.

When i run the mongoimport via cmd line it imports the document but creates a new one instead of updating the existing document.

```
mongoimport --host xx.xxx.x.xxxx --port 27017 -d test -c test --type csv --headerline --file budgettest1.csv --upsert -vvvv
```

I've also tried the following to:

```
mongoimport --host xx.xxx.x.xxxx --port 27017 -d test -c test --type csv --headerline --file budgettest1.csv -vvvv --upsert --upsertFields customer,item,fiscalYear,fiscalMonth,weekID,regularSellingPrice,currentYearPlannedUnits,currentYearPlannedDollars
```

Iv'e used the _id field as a reference and also left it out and in all cases it just creates a new record. Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo Is unable to handle that expression I found out.  I need to drop the collection which in this case does not make sense witht he amount of data being updated vs the amount of data in the collection.  a .js file will need to be created to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

mongoimport --upsert

You can found documenttion here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Im not sure if where its located matter's to to much (correct me if im wrong).  Its already in the code at the end but i did try moving  --upsert after the mongoimport command and it returned the same results..created a new document.

Comment: ah, sorry mate didnt see it, than try --drop